# Extracting 3 levels deep product details. Getting error NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

I am stuck some time now hopefully some one can help me solving the following:

What am I trying to do:
From the following web site https://www.coop.nl/boodschappen I’m trying to go from

1)  Category level:

```
category_url = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block categories')]//a/@href")
```

2)  Product overview level:

```
product_url = response.xpath("//article[contains(@class,'gi b0_12 b2_06 b4_08 listItem')]//div/a/@href").extract()
```

3)  Product detail level:

Extracting and storing the following items:

- Category level: `category_name`, `category_url`
- Product overview level: `product_url`
- Product detail level: `product_name`, `product_description`,
  `product_pricesI`, `product_pricesII`

Currently getting the following error

```
line 21, in parse item['category_name']   = category_name 
NameError: name 'item' is not defined
```

I am using Scrapy 1.5.2 and Python 3.6.4

**Items.py file**

```
import scrapy

class CoopItem(scrapy.Item):
    category_name = scrapy.Field()
    category_url = scrapy.Field()

    product_name = scrapy.Field()
    product_description = scrapy.Field()
    product_pricesI = scrapy.Field()
    product_pricesII = scrapy.Field()
    product_url = scrapy.Field()
```

**coop.py file**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from ..items import CoopItem

class CoopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'coop'
    allowed_domains = ['coop.nl']  
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.coop.nl/boodschappen/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # categories
        #item = CoopItem()
        category_name = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block categories')]//div[contains(@class,'title')]/span/text()")
        category_url = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'block categories')]//a/@href")

        #item['category_name']   = category_name
        #item['category_url']    = category_url

        for href in category_url:
            cat_url = href.extract()
            cat_name = category_name.extract()
            yield Request(url = cat_url,
                          callback = self.parse_products, meta= {'category_name':cat_name, 'category_url':cat_url})

    def parse_products(self, response):
        # Product overview page(s)        
        product_url = response.xpath("//article[contains(@class,'gi b0_12 b2_06 b4_08 listItem')]//div/a/@href").extract()

        #NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.pagination--lister a.next::attr(href)'
            #next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
        NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'pagination--lister')]//a[contains(@rel,'next')]/@href")
        for href in NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR:
            next_page_url = href.extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse_products)

        yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_product_items, meta={'category_name': category_name, 'category_url': category_url, 'product_url': product_url})

    def parse_product_items(self, response):
        # Product detail page

        product_name = response.xpath("//h1[contains(@itemprop,'name')]//text()").extract()
        product_description = response.xpath("//dl[contains(@class,'definitionList')]//text()").extract()
        product_pricesI = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'primeDetails gi b0_12 b3_12 b3_push_01 m-0')]//ins/text()").extract()
        product_pricesII = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'primeDetails gi b0_12 b3_12 b3_push_01 m-0')]//span/text()").extract_first()

        item = CoopItem()
        item['category_name']       = category_name
        item['category_url']        = category_url
        item['product_name']        = product_name
        item['product_description'] = product_description
        item['product_pricesI']     = product_pricesI
        item['product_pricesII']    = product_pricesII
        item['product_url']         = product_url
        yield item
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In `parse` function you commented this code, so there should not be this error.
2. You need you update two of your other functions:

Extract variables from meta:

```
def parse_products(self, response):
    # Product overview page(s)     
    category_name = response.meta['category_name']
    category_url = response.meta['category_url']
    ....

def parse_product_items(self, response):
    # Product detail page
    category_name = response.meta['category_name']
    category_url = response.meta['category_url']
    product_url = response.meta['product_url']
    ....
```

Comment: HI Vezunchik, Thank you for your quick reaction!

The spider is giving the following error:
line 62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Comment: The output son file is giving giving all the category_name items, instead of the selected one. It follows an un logic pattern

Comment: Use `yield Request(response.urljoin(your_url), ...)` or `yield response.follow(your_url, ....)`.

Comment: About second comment: in `parse` use `for href, cat_name in zip(category_url, category_name):`

Comment: Thanks for your input! But it didn't solve the issues.
Any other sugestions?